# Swift: Creating the segue between two controllers does not accept my second view controller

Tags: ios, segue

I am trying to segue between two `uiviewcontrollers` but Swift will not compile my code. Here is my code:

```
prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: "containerSegue", source: self, destination: EventColumnViewController.self), sender: nil)
```

Where EventColumnViewController is my custom ViewController class, and here is the error I get:

```
Cannot find an initializer for type 'UIStoryboardSegue' that accepts an argument list of type '(identifier: String, source: ViewController, destination: EventColumnViewController.Type)'
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Here is my class declaration: `class EventColumnViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to specify a specific segue in the function signature for prepareForSegue.  Instead the function receives whichever segue is triggered and you can perform specific code for a certain segue using if blocks.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "containerSegue") {
        // perform specific code here.
    }
}
```

If you actually want to perform the specific segue named "containerSegue" programatically, you would want to use a different function:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("containerSegue", sender: self)
```

Notice the difference:

- prepareForSegue is used to do setup (such as passing data to the next controller) after a segue has been triggered
- performSegueWithIdentifier actually triggers the segue

Comment: Thank you! This likely will work, but doesn't right now. I implemented this into my UITableView's didSelectItemAtPath method, but now the table item doesn't get highlighted and the segue doesn't occur.

Comment: Hard to know what isn't right, maybe the IBOutlet isn't set up properly?  Here's a decent blog post (not mine) that puts together the concepts you are working with, maybe it will help:  http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-uitableviewcell-taps-swift/